# Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_database@91313886' has not been initialized

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in flutter
I want to link the db file that I have.
There is an error related to initialization, but I don't know what the problem is

> 2022-02-16 17:47:47.530 20199-20218/com.example.flower_sunset_2 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_database@91313886' has not been initialized.
> #0      DatabaseProvider._database (package:flower_sunset_2/database.dart)
> #1      DatabaseProvider.database (package:flower_sunset_2/database.dart:19:9)

```
class DatabaseProvider {
  static final DatabaseProvider provider = DatabaseProvider();

  late Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await createDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  createDatabase() async {
    // Directory docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // String path = join(docsDir.path, "repo_db_senior.db");

    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(databasePath, "repo_db_senior.db");

    // Check if the database exists
    var exists = await databaseExists(path);
    print("database start");

    if(!exists) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Make sure the parent directory exists
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (_) {}

      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join('repo', 'db', 'senior.db'));
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    }
    else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }

    var database = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);
    // var database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: initDB, onUpgrade: onUpgrade);
    return database;
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - repo/db/senior.db
```

Answer (score 0):

your database file names are not matching. In `pubspec.yaml` file you have it as `'senior.db'` while in your code you are looking for `'repo_db_senior.db'`.

Comment: I tried as you said, but I still got the same error.
From the content of the error, the problem seems to be the line with the late.
////////////
2022-02-17 01:08:29.533 31605-31626/com.example.flower_sunset_2 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_database@91313886' has not been initialized

////////////
My code is referring to the site below, and the code on this site is also using _ to write db files.
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md